# How can i change the BufferedImage type?

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage

I am using `ImageIO` to import an Image to store the image components (alpha, red, green, blue) in a byte array. Later on i need to read from this byte array, But i don't know in which sequence the components (I don't know if first element is alpha, second is red ... or not in the array) are stored and is alpha even stored ?

Is there a default sequence ? or Is there a way to change the sequence to some desired one like ABGR or ARGB etc.

Current code for getting the components in the array.

```
    BufferedImage temp;

    try{
        temp = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        ImageArray = ((DataBufferByte)temp.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the java documents didn't help me at all.

Comment: Please show us how your code stores the image components in a byte array.

Comment: @VGR Code uploaded. Now i don't how the components are arranged the array.

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @EJP Sorry i think you did not understand question, the question in short was if i there isn't a default sequence then how can i change the sequence to the desired one. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BufferedImage object in java has two relevant methods:

```
int getRGB(int x, int y)
```

and

```
void setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)
```

In both cases the pixel channels alway follow the same scheme regardless of how the picture is setup. The int rgb is a four byte integer.

The left most byte is the alpha, followed by red then blue then green. That is, argb. Since one byte can hold a small integer from values 0 to 255. Each byte has 256 different individual intensities. The actual bits look like this:

```
aaaaaaaarrrrrrrrggggggggbbbbbbbb
```

To extract the color or alpha you would like to access use the bitwise operators.

If I wanted just the red for example, I could use the bitshift operater to shift the bits 16 places right and then and it with a hex value to extract just that channel:

```
int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
int a = (rgb >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
int g = (rgb >>  8) & 0x000000ff;
int b =       (rgb) & 0x000000ff;
```

Lets see how that plays out. Suppose we already have a color:

```
rgb -> the binary 00101011 10101010 11111111 00000000
```

Then lets shift it 16 bits to the right:

```
00000000 00000000 00101011 10101010
```

Notice, now the alpha is still there...and we don't want it. So we will clear everything but the red bits by anding them:

```
    00000000 00000000 00101011 10101010
and 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
  = 00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010
```

Which is just the red component of color 10101010.

You can also set all three channels of bits using the same line of thinking in reverse:

```
int rgb = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
```

...assuming each channel is already between 0-255.

I always remember how to use the bitwise operators by using the mnemonic 
"set-or clear-and". That means to set a bit to 1 use "or". To clear a bit to 0 use "and". The "<<" and ">>" shift the bits left or right by a number of times specified by the operand on the right of the arrows.

**AMENDED ANSWER (After code was added to question)**

Even though it is discouraged for performance and clarity reasons, the raster can be directly accessed as various arrays. In these cases, the order of bytes follows the Type and Color Model of the image. Here is one such example:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
// If we swap the type, what we put in our for loop will vary greatly
DataBufferByte dbb = ((DataBufferByte)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer());
byte[] bytes = dbb.getData();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
  // modify byte array here with bytes[i];
}
try {
  SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, 100, 100, 3, 100*3, new int[]{2, 1, 0});
  DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(bytes, bytes.length);
  Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, null);
  img.setData(raster);
} catch stuff......
```

If you were to change `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` to `TYPE_3BYTE_RGB`, every third byte (3n) would be red instead of blue in the example above; also, every third plus two (3n+2) byte would be blue instead of red. This would essentially just swap the red and blue bytes.

If `TYPE_3BYTE...` is changed from `BYTE` to `INT`, the array will be an array of bytes instead of ints.

Comment: So that means the `Array[0] is alpha, Array[1] is red, Array[2] is green, Array[3] is blue`. right ?

Comment: If I remember correctly each index into the DataBufferByte is just a byte. So yes, and there should be 4 per pixel. I'm firing up a sample project now to confirm and I'll get right back to you.

Comment: So it turns out once you get to the level of modifying bytes in the actual raster, which is what you are doing, the size of the channels and order are totally dependent on your Component Model. This can be obtained by using the $img.getColorModel().getComponentSize()$ call from a buffered image. If you are creating a buffered image by its constructor this the format is passed in by using BufferedImage.TYPE....

Comment: I created a sample project and modified the bytes in a raster under different color models to confirm. If the color model is a "byte" model. Then each index will be a separate channel. If the model is an "int" model than each index will be a separate pixel.  Even though we can modify the bytes directly in the raster, it is discourage because of optimizations Java does under the hood. You should still use the getRGB and setRGB as described above for performance and clarity. If this is just for the sake of learning knock your self out:)

Comment: I'm going to amend my answer above with an example of how you can write bytes to the raster in the right way.

Comment: But for texture mapping i think get the data for all the textures before running the program is better than `getRGB`, am i wrong ?

Comment: Premature optimization can lead to a lot of work without good results. The way Java's API recommend editing that sort of image data, textures and all is by using the BufferedImage with RGB getters and setters. After you get the deisred results, time how long it takes. Then try again using a byte array. Time that also and compare. The runtime may even be vastly different on different systems. Here is a post that gives more insight if your looking into performance comparisons: 

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75661/java-single-array-best-choice-for-accessing-pixels-for-manipulation

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am not focusing much on optimization as it is just a hobby project, So quick and dirty is fine with me.

Comment: Your welcome:)   I hate how every question gets down votes for arbitrary reasons. Your question was valid.  I think people just down vote because they don't like how the question was asked, or expect it to be formulated so well that it can be answered in one sentence. Sometimes getting general knowledge requires asking general questions.

Comment: I always thought, i am the only one that thinks that users on this site is obsessed with down voting. that's why i rarely post on this site. I think people are more friendly on MSE, CGSE or GDSE, never got a single down vote there. But what can you do, this site is probably the best place for such language specific question.

Comment: Just a quick tip. If you want something like this `aasdf`, then you should put ,` ,before the start of the text and in the end.